# Create a new record using another for default values

Tags: django, django-views

What would be the best way to implement a feature whereby a user selects an existing record **as a template** for the creation of a new one?

Ideally I'd like a list of all existing records in a ListView and the user clicks on one of these records and is taken to a CreateView whereby the fields are populated with the selected record's values as new default, starting values.

Would this method essentially be a standard ListView-to-UpdateView however the save method would instead create a new record instead of updating?

models.py

```
class movies(models.Model):
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fk_producer = models.ForeignKey(producers, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id', )
```

Views.py

```
class movies_list(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = movies
    template_name = 'movies_list.html'

  class movies_create(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = movies
        fields = ['title', 'fk_producer']
        template_name = 'movies_create.html'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.fk_user = self.request.user
            form.save()
            # return super().form_valid(form)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        def get_form_class(self):
            if self.request.GET.get('copy_object'):
            copy_object = movies.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('copy_object'))
            return MyFormClass(instance=copy_object)
        else:
            return MyFormClass
```

urls.py

```
path('create/movie',movies_create.as_view(), name='movies_create'),
```

movies_list.html

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>No.</th>
   <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
    {% for movie in movie %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'movies_create' movie.id %}">{{ movie.title }}</a></td>
  </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

movies_create.html

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div>{{ form|crispy }}</div>
    </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. This is just a simple idea:

Get the id of the object you want as template and pass it as GET parameter. For example https://example.com/create/?copy_object=7

Then, on your views.py, instead `form_class` use the function `get_form_class()`:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('copy_object'):
            copy_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('copy_object'))
            return MyFormClass(instance=copy_object)
        else:
            return MyFormClass
```

EDIT:

The correction of your code:

models.py

```
class movies(models.Model):
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fk_producer = models.ForeignKey(producers, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id', )
```

views.py

```
from .forms import *
class movies_list(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = movies
    template_name = 'movies_list.html'

class movies_create(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = movies
    fields = ['title', 'fk_producer']
    template_name = 'movies_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        # return super().form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('copy_object'):
            copy_object = movies.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('copy_object'))
            return MovieForm(instance=copy_object)
    else:
        return MovieForm
```

forms.py

```
class MovieForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = movies
        fields = ['title','fk_producer'] #fk_user is not necessary because you add it on form_valid function
```

movies_list.html

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>No.</th>
   <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
    {% for movie in movie %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'movies_create' %}?copy_object={{movie.id}}">{{ movie.title }}</a></td>
  </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've updated my question with your solution  - would this be the correct implementation?

Comment: Yes, but lines inside get_form_class() have wrong tabulations. Anyway, you can solve your problem with `MyFormClass(instance=copy_object)`. The only thing left to solve would be how to obtain the object. I have proposed passing it through GET, but I don't know if it would be more convenient to do it via POST or even through kwargs. That depends on you and the purpose of the application. On the other hand, if you edit the question by adding my proposal, the answer has no sense to whoever reads it in the future, hahaha. I think you should leave the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking at your code and it's not correct. I edit my answer and correct the errors.

Comment: Yes, I'll update the question after of course, I implemented your suggestion however the fields on the create html are empty - the url does contain the  correct id however as you predicted. I've updated my question with the create page.